# Import data from multiple CSV files and dynamically store in dataset c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Here i am using this code only for one file to be select and creating one datatable and stored in the dataset..but i want to create multiple datatable for multiple Csv files and store in the dataset. Finally export to CSV from dataset.But it is difficult for ,Please help me ..

//

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int nRows = 0;      //Row Counter
        int icol = 0;       //Index value for Columns -> fArray
        int irow = 0;       //Index value for Row -> fArray
        string[,] fArray;
        string Line;        //Temp string value for storing lines



        #region File Open Parameters
        //file open parameters
        OpenFileDialog fopen = new OpenFileDialog();
        fopen.Title = "Choose file...";
        fopen.Filter = "Comma Seperated Values|*.csv";
        fopen.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        #endregion

        if (fopen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Show file open dialog and check if ok has been pressed
        {
            //#region progress bar initialisation
            ////initialize progress bar
            //pb.Location = new Point(60, 209);
            //pb.Width = 516;
            //pb.Height = 23;
            //pb.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            //pnlStep1.Controls.Add(pb);
            //#endregion

            try
            {
                StreamReader fReader = new StreamReader(fopen.FileName);

                #region Array Index Counters
                //Count Columns for fArray index
                string count = fReader.ReadLine();
                string[] tmpCount = count.Split(',');
                fReader.Close();

                //Count Rows for fArray index
                fReader = new StreamReader(fopen.FileName); //begin reading from line 1
                while ((fReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    nRows++;
                }
                fArray = new string[nRows, tmpCount.Length];
                fReader.Close();
                //End count
                #endregion

                #region Load File Contents
                fReader = new StreamReader(fopen.FileName); //begin reading from line 1
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                dt = ds.Tables.Add("ImportData");

                while ((Line = fReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] row = Line.Split(',');
                    foreach (string column in row)
                    {
                        fArray[irow, icol] = column;
                        icol++;
                    }
                    icol = 0;
                    ////recordCountLabel.Text = irow.ToString(); //NEEDS LOOKING AT
                    ////pb.Value = (irow * 100) / fArray.GetLength(0);
                    irow++;
                }
                //pb.Value = 100;
                fReader.Close();
                #endregion

                #region Add data to dgImport
                for (int i = 0; i < fArray.GetLength(1); i++) //Add Columns to empty DataGridView
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(fArray[0,i]);
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < fArray.GetLength(0); i++) //Insert data into DataGridView (use fArray.GetLength(0) for entire database or use 5 for sample data)
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int j = 0; j < fArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        row[j] = fArray[i, j].Trim();
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }                    
                #endregion

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk.\r\nOriginal error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```